# JQuery plugin dotdotdot not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6HKJZ/3/

This is the part of CSS that causes troubles:

```
.r .rp{
  max-width:50%;
}
.r .r2{
  padding:5px;
  max-height:60px;
  background-color:#292929;
}
```

And this is the Javascript code:

```
$(".rp, .r2").dotdotdot();
```

I get informations from an external page, everything worked before, but now it does not.

This is what I get on my site:
[image]

Everything is correct but it's not working...

P.S. Sorry about bad formatting

Comment: `.dotdotdot();`???????

Comment: @Pilot This plugin uses this function. http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl

Comment: @Xriuk, because you didnt link in the dotdotdot library file into the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pevans02/6HKJZ/2/

Comment: @PatrickEvans I thought I linked it... But on my site there is, but it doesn't work. You can see it here http://www.xriuk.com/album/1 by clicking on Reviews

Comment: In your fiddle, you can included external resources, so add the dotdotdot plugin.  Right now, the fiddle is throwing an error because `dotdotdot()` is not a function.

Comment: @PatrickEvans inside the `func.js` file, in the function `populateSection()`, at the point `name == "#product_reviews"`

Comment: I think you are calling it too quickly, the parser may not have added the elements to the page yet when the dotdotdot call is executed. Try encapsulating the call in a setTimeout of 1 or 100 and see if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call `dotdotdot()` it is to early stage to calculate domElements. I wired thing to a button click and it is working.

http://jsfiddle.net/6HKJZ/5/

I don't know when you call it exactly but try jquery dom ready event

```
$(function(){
   //Your code
});
```

if this does not work try to call it little bit later with a `setTimeout`

Comment: The function you wrote didn't work, but `setTimeout` did. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AS I understand it you are trying to use a jQuery plugin that adds the method "dotdotdot". Your fiddle only includes jQuery, not the dotdotdot library.

If you check your console, running your project, does it give an "undefined" on the line it runs "dotdotdot"? It does on the fiddle.

I included the lib on this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6HKJZ/4/. And it works.

```
$(".rp, .r2").dotdotdot();
```

Comment: Running the mentioned fiddle on Chrome works, what browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox, checked FireBug, does not output any error, the plugin actually parses the strings, cause it adds `word-wrap:break-word`, but it does not ellipse it...

Comment: Did you check the plugin site? Does it work there? Seems to be a bug in FireFox? Works just fine on Chrome.